# What does .activate do in google scripts?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-workspace

```
sheetFunction {
  var sourceFile   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1asdasdasdasdasd");

  // Set sheet
  var masterSheet  = sourceFile.getSheetByName("Master");
  masterSheet.activate
}

cellFunction {
  var sourceFile   = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1asdasdasdasdasd");

  // Set sheet
  var masterSheet  = sourceFile.getSheetByName("Master");
  masterSheet.getRange("A1").activate
}
```

I'm starting out on google scripts and trying to create some simple functions. Was referring to some functions over the net. What does the activate mean in the 1sheetFunction and what is the difference with cellFunction?

Comment: Welcome. The syntax in your code is wrong. Regarding "activate" see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate. By the way, please include a brief description of your search/research efforts as si suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the example at the official site:

> Sets the active sheet in a spreadsheet, with the option to restore the most recent selection within that sheet. The Google Sheets UI displays the chosen sheet unless the sheet belongs to a different spreadsheet.
>
> *// Set the first sheet as the active sheet and select the range D4:F4*.
> `spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(firstSheet).getRange('D4:F4').activate();`

Please read more about it at: [`setActiveSheet(sheet, restoreSelection)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactivesheetsheet,-restoreselection)